# SyntaxError with list comprehension on "not in" operator

Tags: python, list, syntax-error

I'm trying to randomly split a list `X` with `len(X) = 150` into two lists `X_train` and `X_test` with `len(X_train) = 105` and `len(X_test) = 45`.

```
split = np.random.choice(150, 105)
X_train = [X[i] for i in split]
X_test = [X[i] for i not in split]
```

But in line 3 I get a SyntaxError.

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: `for i not in split`  is not valid Python syntax - and what would it mean? If `i` is not in something, where should it be?

Comment: You can't use `in` with `for` loop.

Comment: @Anwarvic Of course you can. `for i in range(..)` is a basic construct.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, Sorry, I meant `not in` with `for` loop... thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Why can I use `in` with `for` but not `not in`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I thought of the expression as either `i` is in the list `split` or not.

Comment: If `split = [42, -3.14, 777]`, `for i in split` means that `i` will take the values 42, -3.14, then 777. What could `for i not in split` mean? There's an infinity of things that aren't in `split`... By which one would you start?

Comment: Now I get it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by

```
split = random.sample(range(len(X)), 105)
X_train = [X[i] for i in split]
X_test = [X[i] for i in [i for i in [i for i in range(len(X)) if i not in split]]]
```

That will create you a list of a random unique number of 105 items and will and then it will extract to X_train all the randoms number indexes and to X_test it will extract all the 45 number that not in the split list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list to split you could just [slice it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

```
from random import randint

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
s = randint(0, len(a))
print(a[:s])
print(a[s:])
```